# Naming two Foreign Keys in the same object

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2008-r2, ef-database-first

I have two foreing keys in the table "CAR" related to the same table "Image".

When I'm checking the tt files the Image objects have the followed names: ( Image / Image1 )

What I need to do If I want the same name provided on the fk? "FrontImage/BackImage"??

Foreing Key Relationship Identity:

```
FK_Car_FrontImage
FK_Car_BackImage
```

EF:

```
    public partial class Car{ 
        public long Id { get; set; }    
        public Nullable<long> FrontImageId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> BackImageId { get; set; }  

        public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
        public virtual Image Image1 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937193/improve-navigation-property-names-when-reverse-engineering-a-database)