# Changing the navigation property names in Database First

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ef-database-first, domain-model

I have a bit of a problem. I have solution with projects

- BusinessLayer
- DataAccessLayer
- Domain Model

My DataAccessLayer contains edmx file and DomainModel tt file with model classes.

I changed tt file according to [Improve navigation property names when reverse engineering a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937193/improve-navigation-property-names-when-reverse-engineering-a-database)
and after that I get an error .. model is not part of the context exception.

This is the code that throws exception:

```
public static TestViewModel GetTestByPIN(string pin)
    {

        TestViewModel clFO = new TestViewModel();


        var client = from cl in db.Tests
                     where cl.PIN == pin
                     select cl;
```

Can anybody help me?