# How to change class properties name generation in Entity Framework Code First from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, ef-code-first

I have a database with a lot of tables, and table `X` has many foreign keys to table `Y`. When I use `Entity Framework Code First` to generate `C#` model corresponding to may database the class `X` has a lot of properties of type `Y` called `Y`, `Y1`, ... `Yn`. For example:

```
public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
public virtual Author Author1 { get; set; }
public virtual Author Author2 { get; set; }
```

And I want to have something like:

```
public virtual Author Writer { get; set; }
public virtual Author Supervisor { get; set; }
public virtual Author Reviewer { get; set; }
```

Coresponding to mai `SQL` table columns:

```
[WriterId] [int] NOT NULL,
[SupervisorId] [int] NOT NULL,
[ReviewerId] [int] NOT NULL,
```

I know that I can add partial classes to add extra properties like in below example:

```
public virtual Author AuthorWriter 
{
    get
    {
        return this.Author1;
    }
    set
    {
        this.Author1 = value;
    } 
}
```

but I would have to much code to write. So my question is if is there a way in `Visual Studio 2013` to configure how virtual properties names are generated by `Entity Framework`?

I mention that I do not want to change the generation of `C#` model way because the database is larger and I do not have access to modify its structure, moreover if the database is changed I should regenerate my `C#` model.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Improve navigation property names when reverse engineering a database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937193/improve-navigation-property-names-when-reverse-engineering-a-database)