# Why edmx file is affecting runtime behavior

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t4, edmx

I have created an edmx file with a database first approach and have adapted a navigation property name from `User.Contact1` to `User.DefaultContact` in the T4 template like below

```
    string foreignKeyName = navigationProperty.RelationshipType.Name;
    string customizedPropertyName = customizedPropertyNames
             .Where(x => x.EntityName == entity.Name && foreignKeyName == x.ForeignKeyName)
             .FirstOrDefault()?.PropertyName;
    string propertyDefinition = codeStringGenerator.NavigationProperty(navigationProperty, customizedPropertyName);
```

The name is changed successfully but it causes a runtime MetadataException

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException : Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
The relationship 'Model.FK_User_Contact' was not loaded because the type 'User' is not available.
The following information may be useful in resolving the previous error:
The required property 'Contact1' does not exist on the type 'User'.
```

Then when I also changed the navigation property name in edmx manually, the error went away.

```
    <EntityType Name="User">
      <NavigationProperty Name="DefaultContact" Relationship="Self.FK_User_DefaultContact" FromRole="User" ToRole="Contact" />
    </EntityType>
```

My questions are

1. Why is edmx file affecting the runtime behavior(fixed the exception)? Shouldn't it be just a design time tool? After the edmx modification, I re-run all the T4 templates. It causes no change in all the generated C# code(verified in git)
2. What is the root cause of the error. Is there anyway to fix this with just T4 template adaptation, without manual editing of edmx file?

#### Update:

My assumption that edmx is only for design time is wrong. It is also compiled into 3 embedded resource files (.csdl, .msl, .ssdl). The navigation property name is defined also in the .csdl file. 
Adapting the T4 template will create C# model class that does not match the csdl file, this is what's causing the MetadataException.

Then the question is, how come there are so many [Stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937193/improve-navigation-property-names-when-reverse-engineering-a-database/13064383#13064383) suggesting adapting T4 template is the way to go to generate customized navigation property names?

Comment: You can modify the T4 template to change the output. For example if you want to derive from a custom class, for additional functionality. Just remember you could just as easily (better to) rename properties in the EDMX designer surface because the template **is** reading the edmx to generate its output.